# Snort gives "could not create the registry key" error for multiple kinds of operations

Tags: snort

I've set up a host-only network in Virtualbox consisting of a Kali linux machine and a Windows 7 machine (the host is running OS X). I have Snort installed on Windows 7 and am attempting to verify that it's able to communicate with the Kali machine via multiple means, however I'm getting the same non-specific error in each case.

Specifically, if I attempt to run Snort in IDS mode to detect a ping from the Kali machine (`snort -dev -l ./log -h 192.168.1.0/24 -c [path to config file]`) or in Test mode to see if a rule I wrote is loading properly (`snort -T -c [path to config file]`) Snort will start, run through its startup sequence, load preprocessors and then abruptly close after `Log directory = ./log` with the message "could not create the registry key".

As far as I can tell no error message is being displayed at any point, which is odd as any time I ran into this situation while setting Snort up there was an associated error message detailing why the operation failed.

Also note that I can run snort just using `snort -i 1 -c [config file] -A console`, however this mode doesn't seem to be detecting any incoming traffic when I try to ping the Windows machine from the Kali machine.

Comment: There are lots of search results for this error. Have you tried any of those?